# tibrvsend add 'DATA=' and 'value=XXX.XXX' to the message

Tags: tibco

When I execute: tibrvsend network service daemon SUBJECT 'MESSAGE'

I expected that on tibrvlisten I get SUBJECT message={MESSAGE}, but I always get SUBJECT message={DATA="MESSAGE" value=XXXXX.XXX}

How to send message to get exactly the same message I send with tibrvsend, without DATA=" and value = XXXXX.XX ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DATA format is hard-coded in the tibrvsend binary - so you cannot send a message with standard tibrvsend that will not get wrapped in "DATA".

However, tibrv comes with the source code for tibrvsend in perl/java/c/c++ versions. So you can easily change the format and compile your own custom tibrvsend. See the src/examples directory in your tibrv installation for the source code.